# Custom theme .mo translation file not working

Tags: translation, localization, plugin-qtranslate

I have a custom .mo file named ne_NP uploaded in the languages directory. Nepali language is enabled with qTranslate and define('WPLANG', 'ne_NP'); is in wp-config.php as well.

Yet the theme translations are not working, the translated texts are still in english. Translating posts and pages is working properly.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: What are you trying to translate? WordPress? A theme? a plugin?

Comment: A theme. I'm updating my question.

Comment: Doublecheck that you're using the [correct textdomain](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Text_Domains), have the textdomain listed in the [style.css header](https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header#Theme_File_Header_Example), and have [loaded it](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Loading_a_Text_Domain) correctly.